# use pep8 to check the coding style in jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter, pep8

I have a problem in using pep8 to check the coding style in jupyter notebook.

install by:

in[1]

```
%install_ext https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiggyF/notebooks/master/pep8_magic.py
```

out

```
Installed pep8_magic.py. To use it, type:
  %load_ext pep8_magic
```

load by

in[2]

```
%load_ext pep8_magic
```

out

```
The pep8_magic extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
  %reload_ext pep8_magic
```

use it by

in[3]

```
%%pep8
a=1
```

out

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3b6f6dbc7761> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'pep8', u'', u'\na = 1')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2118             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2119             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2120                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2121             return result
   2122 

/home/cs/.ipython/extensions/pep8_magic.pyc in pep8(line, cell)
     38     with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
     39         # save to file
---> 40         f.write(bytes(cell + '\n', 'UTF-8'))
     41         # make sure it's written
     42         f.flush()

TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

It seems that I have installed and loaded it successfully but I can not run the cell magic.

Later I found the problem was caused by some differences between python2 and python3. By using `io.Bytes` and  `f.write(cell+'\n')` in `pep2_magic.py`, it worked. But unfortunately, it still can't output information of pep8, like the example here [pep8 style guide](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SiggyF/notebooks/blob/master/styleguide.ipynb)